# GUI button and entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project for CS and it is dealing with GUI's in python.
It's a three part project with 3 different classes. In the last class when I am trying to add a button widget or entry widget I keep on getting an error:

```
global name 'Button' is not defined
```

---

```
from Spotter import Spotter
from Cloud import Cloud
from Tkinter import tkinter, Tk, StringVar
from random import randint
import time
import math

class Cloudspotting (Spotter):

     # create the buttons
     def __init__(self, root):
         Spotter.__init__(self, root)
         # the result binding variable
         self.result = StringVar()
         self.result.set('')

         # create the buttons and result entry
         self.startBtn = Button(self.frame, text='Start', command=self.start)
         self.stopBtn = Button(self.frame, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
         self.clearBtn = Button(self.frame, text='Clear', command=self.clear)
         self.resultEntry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.result, state='readonly')

         # display the buttons and entry on the frame
         self.startBtn.grid(row=2, column=1)
         self.stopBtn.grid(row=2, column=2)
         self.clearBtn.grid(row=2, column=3)
         self.resultEntry.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2)

         # clouds
         self.clouds = None
```

Comment: You need a `from Tkinter import Button` near the top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly import tkinter. I recommend *not* using global imports. Remove all of your attempts at importing tkinter and do it like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...
self.result = tk.StringVar()
...
self.startBtn = tk.Button(...)
...
```

Notice how this imports tkinter with the name `tk` (for brevity), and then prefix tkinter classes with `tk.`. This makes it clear that you are using the `Button` class from tkinter and not from some other module.